# How would I find all open PR's on any repository where I have contributor access rights

Tags: github, github-api

All too often I'm loosing track of open PR's to one of my repositories. I'm looking for a way to quickly show me all open PR's I have commit rights to.

is:open is:pr and mentioned:me all help, but those will include PR's to repost repositories I don't own or have write access to.